How to add ",a" flag to the filename delivered in maildir by procmail?
I learned that by adding ",a" to the file name in a maildir, the Evolution software considers the mail as an important message.
So I would like to tag some messages using Procmail but whatever I do, I go around in circles, because I do not know the file name before it is delivered by Procmail, and when it is already delivered, it is immediately renamed by various external mechanisms by moving it from new to cur.
Is there a solution only with Procmail?
I know other solutions, but they do not interest me here.

Your current question is rather too vague. If you can show us what you tried and/or under which conditions the delivered file should be renamed, I'm sure we can work it out; but in its current form, this looks a lot like "do my homework (without seeing the actual assignment)". Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for what's on-topic.

Strong hint: LASTFOLDER contains the file name from the latest delivery action.

Curious: is Evolution accessing the maildir directly or via a protocol such as IMAP?

And, is Evolution (or something else) constantly scanning your inbox? I don't think the move from new to tmp should be instantaneous but if you have something actively reading at the same time, I suppose you could get a race condition.
